# iframe holding previous php session info

Tags: php, iframe, session-variables

I am working on an application where a link is opening up an iframe containing a form. The pre populated form inputs depend on the user logged in. This works fine for the first person who logs in but if the user logs out and leaves the browser open for another user to log in, when navigating to that iframe, it still populates based on the original logged in user.

When doing a print_r of $_SESSION, it shows all the session info of the original user. But if I print the session info on say the landing page after login, it shows the correct user info for the currently logged in user.

Logout code:

```
function LogOut() {
    session_start();

    $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

    $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;

    unset($_SESSION[$sessionvar]);

    if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])):
        setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-7000000, '/');
    endif;

    session_destroy();
}
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: are you destroying the session when user logs out ?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried $_SESSION = array();

Answer (score 0):

## Fully implement your logout behavior

> if the user logs out and leaves the browser open... [ the iframe
>   $_SESSION ] shows all the session info of the original user.

There's your problem.

**Any fully implemented logout behavior needs to clear both the Browser cookies, and the $_SESSION data.**

## Browser cache

What is most likely happening is that the browser is caching results for the url in that iFrame, and/or still has user-data in the cookies.

#### Implement a user-session key, or load the token in the iFrame url.

Solving this problem sufficiently to prevent this issue in the future, following steps will likely be necessary:

iFrame url:

- Including the session token, or a randomly generated token, as a querystring argument to the iFrame url. Required for the iframe to load, and checked server-side against the $_SESSION to ensure it matches the currently logged-in user.
- Set a timeout for this iFrame. Part of your problem is what happens if the user leaves this tab open, but logs out from a different tab? There's nothing you can do in this case, except implementing a timeout, or on the iframe implementing a regular ajax check for a matching session.

Logout:

- Clear the browser cookies.
- Clear the session.

#### Regarding clearing the session

> In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be
>   unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default
>   behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) may be
>   used for that.

[PHP Session Destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Calling `session_destroy()`, or setting `$_SESSION = array()` does *not* delete the session cookie (preserving the previous users' session). To properly destroy the session, call `setcookie()`.

```
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

From: [PHP session_destroy Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#refsect1-function.session-destroy-examples)

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have updated the question to include the logout code. I believe we are already doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: @SteveBrown, take a closer look at [PHP Session Destroy: Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#refsect1-function.session-destroy-examples). Also, carefully map the steps (and open tabs) that may result in the iFrame/Browser preserving the content of the iframe (**Browser Cache** section of my answer).

Comment: @SteveBrown, one way or another, if the iFrame is reloaded on the second login, and print `$_SESSION` data on that load of the iFrame displays the data from the previous user, the `$_SESSION` has not been properly destroyed.

Comment: ok thank you, I will look into that more. I also tried just changing the link from pulling up an iframe to redirecting to a new page and it still had the same issue.

Comment: @SteveBrown, *then you are not properly destroying the session*. See adjustment at end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. That code also did not solve the issue on either the iframe or using  a straight link.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might cause this, is that somehow the server is preserving expired session. If that's the case, add a new variable to the session ( ex: expired = true ). Check for that variable as one of the first actions on page-load, and generate a new time if that is the case. REALLY doesn't make sense that a session destroyed this way is still showing up. Makes me think there's something bodd happening on the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Other priorities took over on this. We still haven't figured out what is going on here. I've even included a callback function that destroys the session on close of the iframe which it does but it destroys the user session all together and when you log back in and navigate to that page, the old session still exists.

Comment: As I said, the only possible explaination is that your server is preserving session history. I.E.: Recovering deleted sessions. Add your own random token to the session vars, store it, mark it expired on completion, and base tour session logic on the state of that token. Or, do a really deep dive on session handling and retrieval on your webserver (Apache/nginx)